# 404 on Beer Meta image

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, images, 404-not-found

The Beer Stack Exchange icon on Data Explorer is missing or misdirected. The HREF points to an image that seems inappropriately named: [cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beermeta/img/**apple-touch-icon**.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beermeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

[image: Beer Meta icon]

Comment: More tragically, the Beer 404 error page is a great opportunity for humor, but is currently generic.

Comment: Beer was renamed to Alcohol so the correct url would be: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/alcoholmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png` and `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/alcohol/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be all good now:

> [image]