# A site URL changed and now its icon in SEDE is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, favicon, cdn

This has [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291961/323179), and it's happened again, all because Cognitive Sciences recently was renamed [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/), with a change to the URL.

The first thing that needs to be fixed is the name should be changed, as it uses has the old name.

The second problem, due to the URL changing from cogsci.stackexchange.com to psychology.stackexchange.com is that the icons are broken.

These are the right URLs:

`https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychology/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

`https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychologymeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

---

These problems affect both the Psychology & Neuroscience main and meta site listings. And it's not just one page either: the problems are seen [in the dropdown](https://data.stackexchange.com/cogsci/queries), on the [main list](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and on the [compose query page](https://data.stackexchange.com/cogsci/query/new).

It's currently also affecting <s>Writers</s> Writing, which has been [renamed more than a year ago](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/this-site-is-now-writing).

It also currently [affects Code Golf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362626/355458)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data dump, Programmers and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293127/data-dump-programmers-and-software-engineering)

Comment: [An exact duplicate of this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307661/cogsci-is-now-psychology-se-but-sede-isnt-aware-of-it) was closed as a duplicate of the above post by an SE employee.

Comment: @Ano Not a duplicate of the Programmers/Software Engineering post because Software Engineering's icon is [not broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobS5.png).

Comment: I know, but a recently posted question that duplicates this one exactly, and the exact same report but for Beer.SE, were closed as duplicates of that question by an SE employee.

Answer (score 12):

The issues will be quick hacked (fixed if you wish) running the following SQL update statement on the Data.StackExchange  database by someone with full database access.

That sites table does get/should be populated now and then (on changes) from a different source so maybe it is wiser to fix that instead.

The script fixes Writing, CogSci and [CodeGolf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362626)

I have tested below script [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1091404)

```
Use [Data.StackExchange]

-- writing
update Sites 
set BadgeIconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writing/img/apple-touch-icon.png'
  , ImageUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writing/img/logo.png'
  , IconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writing/img/icon-16.png'
  , Longname = 'Writing'
where Id = 84 

-- writing Meta
update Sites 
set BadgeIconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writingmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png'
  , ImageUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writingmeta/img/logo.png'
  , IconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/writingmeta/img/icon-16.png'
  , Longname = 'Writing Meta'
where Id = 85


-- CosSci
update Sites 
set BadgeIconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychology/img/apple-touch-icon.png'
  , ImageUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychology/img/logo.png'
  , IconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychology/img/icon-16.png'
  , Longname = 'Psychology & Neuroscience'
where Id = 146 

-- CogSci Meta
update Sites 
set BadgeIconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychologymeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png'
  , ImageUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychologymeta/img/logo.png'
  , IconUrl = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychologymeta/img/icon-16.png'
  , Longname = 'Psychology & Neuroscience Meta'
where Id = 147

-- CodeGolf
update Sites 
set  Longname =  'Code Golf and Coding Challenges'
where Id = 92
```

For reference here is what the icons will look like:

#### Writing

BadgeIconUrl

> [image]

ImageUrl

> [image]

IconUrl

> [image]

#### writing Meta

BadgeIconUrl

> [image]

ImageUrl

> [image]

IconUrl

> [image]

#### CogSci

BadgeIconUrl

> [image]

ImageUrl

> [image]

IconUrl

> [image]

#### CogSci Meta

BadgeIconUrl

> [image]

ImageUrl

> [image]

IconUrl

> [image]

Answer (score 10):

This has been updated and should now be showing the correct names and icons for:

- Writing
- Writing Meta
- Psychology & Neuroscience
- Psychology & Neuroscience Meta
- Code Golf and Coding Challenges
- Code Golf and Coding Challenges Meta

Comment: Were you able to fix this so it will not "break" with name changes in the future or was that not possible in the end?

Comment: @rene no I didn’t implement a permanent fix…yet.

Comment: Bummer ... we'll keep on eye on it then. Thanks for the effort! Appreciated!

Comment: A new request to fix site names -> [Some sites names shown in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the current site name. Is this a bug or a feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389022/1359324)