# Capitalization inconsistencies between the favicon.ico and icon-16.png pictures for several non-designed sites

Tags: discussion, favicon, capitalization

Well this is very unimportant, but captured my attention.

Linguistics.SE favorite icon in browser capitalises only the L, but in [Tabs Outliner](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) (just installed) capitalises all the three letters.

I haven't really cleared caches yet, but I hadn't used Chromium for a very long time, and [Tabs Outliner is just installed, so I really doubted clearing caches could help. I was browsing with Opera before today.](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/68879/)

I thought it feels like maybe [Tabs Outliner](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) is fetching the favorite icon from some obsolete source?

[image]

You can see the vi.SE with different capitalisation too.

Directly requesting https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico will redirect me to https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/linguistics/img/favicon.ico and show the favorite icon as seen in the browser tab.

Why does this happen?

Had those favorite icons at some point the capitalisation as seen in [Tabs Outliner](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl)?

---

I've since then found a capitalization inconsistency between https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/linguistics/img/favicon.ico and https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/linguistics/img/icon-16.png after [A site URL changed and now its icon in SEDE is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306338/a-site-url-changed-and-now-its-icon-in-sede-is-broken) has been bumped to the homepage by Community♦ and I found several links there and was able to forge the link I wanted. Same inconsistency can be found for the correspondent [vi](//vi.stackexchange.com/) links.

Maybe you thought the icon-16 is obsolete and so ceased editing it? But for good or bad is what [Tabs Outliner](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) is still using, isn't it?