# SEDE calls Code Golf Stack Exchange by its old name

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, code-golf

[As of May 30'th 2019](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17725/66833), [Code Golf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)'s new official name is **Code Golf and Coding Challenges**. However, [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) hasn't updated this:

[image: screenshot with "Programming Puzzles and Code Golf" circled]

I know this is a minor bug, but it shouldn't take much effort to change this.