# Please fix the "celebrating SE sites that are 10 years old" blog post: remove "Area 51 Discussions" and update the names of sites and the network

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, site-name

Currently, there's a table with a list of sites in the blog post [Celebrating the Stack Exchange sites that turned 10 years old](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/18/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/):

> Graphic Design
> Database Administrators
> Science Fiction
> Area 51 Discussions
> Code Review
> Code Golf
> Quantitative Finance
> Project Management
> Skeptics
> Drupal Answers
> Fitness and Nutrition
> Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair
> Parenting

> Musical Practice and Performance
> Software Quality Assurance and Testing
> German Language and Usage
> Japanese Language and Usage
> Gardening and Landscaping
> Philosophy
> Travel

First off, Area 51 isn't a normal site, and it's weird to include its meta site in this list. It probably shouldn't be in this list at all since it really isn't a proper site.

Secondly, half of the names of the sites in this are... outdated. For instance:

- Science Fiction is called Science Fiction & Fantasy
- Code Golf is called Code Golf & Coding Challenges
- Fitness and Nutrition has been renamed Physical Fitness
- The language sites no longer have "and Usage" in their name, with the exception of English.SE
- Music's full name is Music Practice & Theory
- Most sites that have "and" in their name use an ampersand, not the word

There's also a weird break in the list where it splits into a second table for no apparent reason.

It looks like someone did a query in Data.SE (or the internal version) for sites that were ten years old, got the original names of the sites, and just stuck them in a table without double-checking anything.

Also, in the tagline - "We’re more than just StackOverflow.com; here’s a few of the sites in the Exchange network that have been around for a decade!" - it refers to the "Exchange network", which, uh, isn't the name of the network. That should be the *Stack* Exchange network.

Could this please be at least cleaned up a little?

Comment: I guess by now Ben Popper would have been question banned here for having his contributions down voted for lack of research ...

Comment: Taryn did an awesome job a couple of months ago to fix the public SEDE site names: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364168

Comment: @rene I don't think Ben Popper made the query himself. More likely he asked someone to get the names, and that's what he got. Sad part is he didn't bother to check, at all.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to us - we're looking into this and we'll see if we can get this cleaned up. :)

Comment: It looks like the page has been removed for editing.  The link doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796)

Comment: @hazzey true, and sad. It should not take hours to edit. Proper action would be to 1) get correct names, 2) edit with correct names and proper formatting, it should take **minutes**. Pity they choose to just remove the hand instead of taking care of the wound.

Comment: Anyway, this made me think of new feature request, asking to have blog posts reviewed by high rep users or moderators before being published. This will prevent embarrassing things like this. (Content editors of SE are not to blame, it's not their job to know the sites, or even SE. They just write)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 someone just posted that feature request for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368758/have-blog-posts-be-reviewed-by-mods-before-posting

Comment: @CaveJohnson heh, well it got my upvote. Pity most think otherwise, but nothing I can do. :/

Comment: @hazzey - the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20210818135309/https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/18/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/) has the original article for reference..

Answer (score 19):

We've unpublished the blog post temporarily to fix the points mentioned in this question - thanks for bringing them to our attention so that we could get them addressed quickly. We also wanted to add a bit more to the post about the sites that we could share with people seeing the celebration post, so you'll see it return to the blog soon, once we have that ready to go.

I'll follow up with an update here once the new post is up.

---

#### Update!

As you may have noted, the blog post is back up! We've fixed all of the issues that you mentioned and we also expanded each section to say a bit more about each site and include some featured questions and their top tag.

This was really a team effort and everyone deserves some credit for their part in it. So, in somewhat chronological order:

- Thanks to Mith and others here on MSE for bringing this to our attention and asking us to address these issues.
- Thanks to Philippe who, while on travel, got on calls from the airport to get the ball rolling and coordinate getting the blog post unpublished and tasking people with fixing it.
- Thanks to Juan for doing the actual post editing and for drafting descriptions of each site and finding top questions and tags. He also quickly jumped in to fix the problematic links that a couple of y'all found when we republished the blog.
- I want to also thank the mods on many of these sites along with some of the chat regulars on others for jumping in with less than 24 hours to get me some great descriptive text and links to exemplary questions they love. I know that was hard and a short deadline but I appreciate the effort!

We appreciate your patience as we got this addressed and we hope the new post is something you all can enjoy as we celebrate these 19 sites - Plus Area 51 - on reaching the 10 year mark. We've got a great template now for how these posts should look, so we'll hopefully be able to avoid these issues when celebrate anniversaries in the future!

Comment: Post looks like it's back up - update, please? :)

Comment: And let's not forget to thank Catija, who called me at the airport to tell me to get on calls - advice which I followed slavishly, of course.

Comment: What an incredible response to what any other company would've seen as a mundane complaint that doesn't deserve any attention. Pulling down the blog post, contacting all the mods, spending time rewriting everything... thank you Catija!

Comment: JonathanReez- thank you for the nice words.  That post, however, didn't reach the standards that we aspire to, and I'm really glad we got a chance to fix it.  So I'll add my thanks to @Mithical, who called it to our attention.  We'll do better.