# "Celebrating 10 years" link in Bulletin leads to error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found, community-bulletin

Clicking the link ["Celebrating the Stack Exchange sites that turned 10 Years old"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/18/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/?cb=1) fails.

Link is at the top right of the first snapshot

[image: celebrating 10 years]

---

[image: result of clicking link]

Comment: See [Please remove "Area 51 Discussions" from the "celebrating SE sites that are 10 years old" blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368730), especially the comments there. It is being updated to address some issues.

Comment: (and the side bar links are heavily cached, so it'll take a while for the link to disappear).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  FYI - I wouldn't have known that specific question/answer is related to what I'm seeing though, because I can't tell what the Area 51 discussions thing is.  
It feels like insider info that as a consumer I wouldn't know.  Or it could just be me. Also, I like snapshots.  

Comment: I completely get that; I wasn't voting to close this nor commenting to punish you for not knowing! Just trying to ensure everyone is in the clear that the link is gone on purpose and why, and why it'll take a bit of time to clear up.

Comment: Already reported on MSO: [Look like the blog link is broken](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410862/4642212).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for clearing that up, but also I wasn't upset about closing this either.  Just wanted to provide user feedback from an outsider's perspective.  All good.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That emoji SVG doesn't look the greatest in dark mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VpXb.png

Comment: This is NOT duplicate of a request to change the blog post. This is a bug report about broken link. Nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't matter a bit why the page is down.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 Technically the questions are not dupes. However the response from Stack Exchange will be duplicated across both questions.

Comment: @Peilonrayz no, it won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not seeing the link any more so I'm going to call this complete.

We unpublished the blog post so that we could fix the issues brought to our attention in the related post - [Please remove "Area 51 Discussions" from the "celebrating SE sites that are 10 years old" blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368730) - it takes a little while for the bulletin to refresh, so this is, at its heart, a caching issue.

Apologies for any inconvenience during the period the broken link was up.