# Magic columns and site:// do not work for alcohol.meta.stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, data-explorer, per-site-meta

The site Beer, Wine & Spirits has the URL https://alcohol.stackexchange.com but in SEDE it uses beer for the main site and beerme for meta.

As far as I can tell, the shortcut `site://` and the magic columns such as `[Post Link]`, `[User Link]`, `[Comment Link]` and `[Suggested Edit Link]` work incorrectly on Alcohol Meta.

Here are some queries you can use for testing this.

- Recent posts: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/beer/query/1808172/most-recent-posts-testing), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/beerme/query/1808172/most-recent-posts-testing)
- Recent comments: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/beer/query/1808173/most-recent-comments-testing), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/beerme/query/1808173/most-recent-comments-testing)
- Recent suggested edits: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/beer/query/1178702/recent-suggested-edits), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/beerme/query/1178702/recent-suggested-edits?num=100).

They seem to work fine for the main site, but not for meta. For example, from the first query you get this URL: https://beer.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292 - which returns 404. (Incidentally, the URL https://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/q/292 redirects to the correct page.) Similarly, I get 404 if I try the links for users, comments and suggested edits.

---

I have posted this on this meta rather on the per-site-meta - maybe some other sites might be influenced too. (I have stumbled upon this one by random.)

There are some older bug reports related to SEDE, broken links and this site - but both of them are already marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [404 on Beer Meta image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291961) and [Data.SE breaks when looking things up on Beer, Wine, and Spirits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296521).

Comment: I'm guessing this is because the redirects had to be recreated after the site switched over to Cloudflare – and not all of these redirects were found/created. I'm guessing the site's Meta was never *actually* located at `beer.meta.stackexchange.com` because the `beer`->`alcohol` URL change happened before the `meta.site`->`site.meta` URL change – and so a redirect wasn't set up for it – but as you point out, this still causes issues when it comes to SEDE. To fix this, a redirect just needs to be set up from `beer.meta.stackexchange.com` to `alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 6):

We had missed setting up [beer.meta.stackexchange.com](https://beer.meta.stackexchange.com)  as an alias after the site's name change, but that is fixed now. This issue should be resolved.